# How to Map a table with a long list of generic columns to a JPA entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Consider this use case :
a mysql table X and a java JPA entiy X.

```
create table X 
(id int(11),
 name varchar(200),
 value1 bigint(16),
 value2 bigint(16),
 value3 bigint(16),
 .
 .
 value100 bigint(16));
```

I would like to map to an entity like this :

```
@Entity("x")
@Table("x")
public class X {

@Id
@Column("id)
public int getId ...

@Column("name")
public String getName ..

@SomeMagicalExpression
public List<Long> getValues()..
}
```

I am well aware of the option to create a join table where each value is a row, I am trying to get away from performing joins.
I would really hate to create a 100 getters and setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a shot in the dark, but maybe the OpenJPA @Columns annotation will suit your needs..

http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ref_guide_mapping_custom.html#ref_guide_mapping_custom_field_conf_extex

Not sure if you could use it to map multiple columns to a collection though.. Maybe subclass ArrayList and override its constructor to take in a number of values to populate the list. (If my assumption that the values used in @Columns must correspond to a constructor is correct..)